# Hint text in MDTextField doesn't work from python code

Tags: python, android, kivy, textfield, kivymd

I'm trying to design an app using kivy MD and I have run into a bug/issue.
When I try to set the hint_text in the MDTextField it just doesn't show in my app, I am using python code to add the widget to a box layout here is the sample code:

```
self.fieldsbl.add_widget(MDTextField(hint_text="Server IP", mode="rectangle"))
```

It displays the widget and the rectangle, but without the hint text, what am I doing wrong?
And btw it works from kv file, I have some specific reasons to NOT use kv file in this project, so I'm doing it completely in python...

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bug in the `MDTextField`. You can get around it by setting the `hint_text` after creating the `MDTextField`:

```
    mdtf = MDTextField(mode="rectangle")
    mdtf.hint_text = "Server IP"
    self.fieldsbl.add_widget(mdtf)
```